# jQuery AJAX success callback not firing in IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, file, upload

I'm pretty new to javascript and I have been searching around for a solution to this problem all day. I found many questions/answers but nothing has worked.

I have a page that has a file upload in it, I would like to run this file through a server-side validation routine and then display the validation result on the page. I have this working great in everything but IE (Safari, Chrome & Chromium, Firefox).

In order to make the file upload work on IE, the user needs to submit the form via a submit button. So I use a conditional comment in HTML to add it onto the page. In javascript I use an IE-detection function I found here. This part works fine.

Here is the function that makes the ajax request:

```
function handleUpload()
{
    showSpinner();

    var dFile = new FormData(document.getElementById("devConsValidate")); // this works in IE but only if called by a submit method 

    $.ajax(
    {
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        url: 'validator.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: dFile,
        dataType: 'JSON',

        processData: false, // this is key for formdata
        contentType: false, // so is this

        success: function(response)
        {
            var result = response.result;
            var validationCode = response.validation_code;
            var errors = response.errors;

            var htmlCode = '<h2>';

            if (result == 'SUCCESS')
                htmlCode += '<font color="green">';
            else
            {
                htmlCode += '<font color="red">';
            }

            htmlCode += 'Validation ' + result + '</font></h3>';

            if (result == "FAIL")
            {
                htmlCode += '</center>';
                for (var i in errors)
                    htmlCode += errors[i] + '<br>';

                htmlCode += '<br><a href="validator_help.php">Validator Help    </a>';
            }
            else
            {
                htmlCode += 'Please use the following code when submitting your request.<br><br><font color ="#00aa54" size="+2">' + validationCode + '</font>';
            }

            // make some beautiful html
            $('#resultsArea').html(htmlCode);
        },

        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) 
        {
            alert('error: ' + errorThrown);
        }
    }); 
}
```

the function handleUpload() is called either on the file change event or on the form being submitted. validator.php returns a json_encoded array of values.

The issue is when using IE, the ajax success callback is never fired and the browser just displays a raw JSON string on a blank page, so the ajax call is working and returning expected data. On other browsers, the success callback fires and the json is parsed and the appropriate code is inserted into a div on the page.

Full javascript file: http://pastebin.com/G9MYBis5

Any ideas?

Comment: you should probably specify the version of IE...

Comment: @maxedison only IE10 has FormData

Comment: If your form submits that means that somewhere in you submit handler an error occurred.

Comment: Why not use the `serialize()` function for form data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so the solution for me was to make this line the first line in my head tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

This got IE10 working, for IE9 and below I just had to make static pages since I am able to upload the file without FormData and just get at it from a basic html form submission instead of AJAX. For this I added submit buttons using conditional comments for IE users.